# Conda-build fails on test with missing dependency

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

For a reason I can not build a conda package. My package is posted on PyPi and accessible by

`pip install molcomplib`

To build a conda package I do:

1. I run grayskull  `grayskull pypi molcomplib`
2. I run `conda build -c conda-forge molcomplib`

It looks like `rdkit` is installed during the process

[image]

But finally, after a long-time build stage, I have:

`molcomplib 1.0.1 requires rdkit, which is not installed.`

Which is strange, because `rdkit` is a direct dependence on my meta.yaml and just can not be ignored by `conda`

```
import: 'molcomplib'
import: 'molcomplib'
+ pip check
molcomplib 1.0.1 requires rdkit, which is not installed.
Tests failed for molcomplib-1.0.1-py_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to /home/sergeyadmin/miniconda3/conda-bld/broken
```

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with local building. Add it to Conda Forge `staged-recipes` and work it out on their CI. But you need to add an actual LICENSE file to your source first (for Conda Forge to accept).

Comment: I checked on conda-forge, it fails with the same error.

Comment: 1. Check the meta.yaml file — is there RDKit in requirements?
2. Are sure that your environment was activated? It's a common issue for windows: https://conda.io/activation